# When I use one base class for two different classes, and change a variable within one class instance, the variable in the other class is also changed?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, constructor

The source code below will raise the exception on the last line. Why the exception is raised if they are two different objects?

```
class BaseClass(object):
    
    accounts = dict()
    
    def AddAccount(self, account_id, account_var):
        if account_id in self.accounts.keys():
            raise Exception('Account already exists')
            
        self.accounts.update({account_id: account_var})
        
class Class1(BaseClass):
    pass

class Class2(BaseClass):
    pass

ACCOUNT_ID = '123'
c1 = Class1()
c2 = Class2()

c1.AddAccount(ACCOUNT_ID, 'abc')
c2.AddAccount(ACCOUNT_ID, 'abc')
```

I've tried call the constructor inside each class, but that don't solve the problem. I did like this inside each class:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

It looks like the `BaseClass` is always a static object. When I change in one object, it will change in the other one.

Comment: *" always a static object. When I change in one object, it will change in the other one."* yes, that's the point of class attributes

Comment: Unlike other languages, Python classes only define class attributes, never instance attributes. Instance attributes are always created by direct modification of instances, though that is typically done via instance methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `accounts` as a variable of the class, instead of an instance variable. You should instead define `accounts` in the `__init__` method of your base class so that it is instantiated with a different reference for each instance of the class that you create.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = dict()
    
    def AddAccount(self, account_id, account_var):
        if account_id in self.accounts.keys():
            raise Exception('Account already exists')
            
        self.accounts.update({account_id: account_var})
```

Answer (score 2):

You've defined a class variable in the body of your `BaseClass`.

Even if you reference it with `self.accounts` it's not an instance variable.

If you wanted an instance variable, for example, you should initialize it in `__init__()` with `self.accounts = {}`